# How do I linking to a non-standard library when building an R package

Tags: r, openssl

I'm trying to build the R openssl package and link it to an openssl library that is a newer version than the one in the systemwide lib64 directory.
The Makevars file simply has:

```
KG_CPPFLAGS=@cflags@
PKG_LIBS=@libs@
```

I can specify my local library by passing a custom library path in the `configure` script. But when I issue `R CMD INSTALL`, the linking command begins with

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o openssl.so [...objects...] -Lmy/path/here -lssl -lcrypto
```

As a result, the linker finds the wrong library (the one in /usr/local/lib64) instead of mine.

How do I adjust the linking command so that it looks for the library *first* in my directory, instead of the system folder.

(Background: I don't have root access and this older version of CentOS (5) doesn't support openssl v1, so I built v1 myself just to compile the R package. But I'm stuck at the linking stage due to whatever magic is happening by R CMD INSTALL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing arguments to R CMD INSTALL. I.e.:

```
R CMD INSTALL . --configure-vars="INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/local/include LIB_DIR=$HOME/local/lib64"
```

But this varies for each package. There's no general solution. 
Instead, read config and src/Makefile.in.